# What is the difference between の中に and の中で?

Tags: word-choice, particle-に, particle-で

I have two sentences having の中に (no naka ni) and の中で (no naka de), and I want to know if they are correctly framed.

If yes, then how does the meaning change?

> 日本{にほん}の食{た}べ物{もの}の中{なか}**に**寿司{すし}が大好{だいす}きです。
> Nihon no tabemono no naka ni sushi ga daisuki desu.
> 日本{にほん}の食{た}べ物{もの}の中{なか}**で**寿司{すし}が大好{だいす}きです。
> Nihon no tabemono no naka de sushi ga daisuki desu.

Please let me know if there are any grammatical mistakes.

Comment: I don't think the first one is grammatically correct. I think 中に would show location here, which wouldn't make any sense because your location is food. On the contrary, の中で is almost a set phrase that means "among"